# (Android) onNavigationItemSelected method not being called

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I'm working on an Android app for an Engineering Design project that includes a drawer. One of my group members elected to use the android.support.design.widget.NavigationView API to do this, and it's been causing us some problems. Our MainActivity class implements onNavigationItemSelectedListener, which I understand acts as a listener for the items in the drawer and other navigation bars. The problem is, when one of these navigation items is selected, the onNavigationItemSelected method that has been implemented is not called (I know this because it's supposed to put out a message through LogCat if it is called). All the references I've found for this API suggest that I've done everything right so far, but I've apparently missed something, so any help is appreciated.

Here is the relevant code from the MainActivity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpNavComponents();
    setUpMapComponents();
    PathfinderDataHandler handler = new PathfinderDataHandler();
}

private void setUpNavComponents()
{
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

private void setUpMapComponents()
{
    mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Log.d(null, "onNavigationItemSelected Called");

    if (id == R.id.buildings)
    {
        // Handle the camera action
        Log.d(null, "Buildings selected");
    }
    else if (id == R.id.blue_phones)
    {
        Log.d(null, "Blue Phones selected");
    }
    else if (id == R.id.bus_stops)
    {
        Log.d(null, "Bus Stops selected");
    }
    else if (id == R.id.pedways)
    {
        Log.d(null, "Pedways selected");
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Here is the code from activity_main_drawer.xml (Which holds all the items for the drawer)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group
    android:checkableBehavior="all"
    android:enabled="true">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/buildings"
        android:title="@string/building_show_select"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_item"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/blue_phones"
        android:title="@string/blue_phone_select"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_item"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bus_stops"
        android:title="@string/bus_stop_select"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_item"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/pedways"
        android:title="@string/pedway_select"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_item"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</group>
```

Here is the code for activity_main.xml, which adds the activity_main_drawer to the NavigationView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Another thing to note is that I'm using Switch items instead of regular Menu items.

And before anyone says anything, YES I know this API is depreciated and I should be using NavigationUI in AndroidX, but I don't have time to refactor the app so I have to make do with this.

Comment: onNavigationItemSelected should be override, why its look a normal, can u please check again

Comment: It is an overridden method, I just left the tag out. I'll update the post.

Comment: can you provide the `xml` where you add the menu to the `NavigationView` inside the `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: Ok, it should be there now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a non `null` tag for Log.d(String, String), else there will be nothing written to Logcat.

I tried with

```
Log.d(null, "HelloWorld");
Log.d("TEST", " HelloWorld");
```

and got only one line in Logcat:

[image]

Comment: Well, that got the logs to show up, but the method still isn't called if I toggle the swipe bar on the menu item. It is called if I click on the actual menu item itself though.

Comment: @Jon Derr - AFAIK that's how it's supposed to work: an OnClickListener for menu items. "Selected" == "Clicked". The additional functionality may be possible with some additional tweak but to be honest I don't understand what you mean by "toggle the swipe bar". Maybe because I also don't know a Switch menu item. Are they from some library?